# Using BeutifulSoups find() but getting pythons find() instead

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am learning web scraping and I've run into a problem. I am trying to use the .find() method built into BS4 but it is seeing the code as Pythons built in .find()

I am not sure how to fix it. I have tried using .soup.find() but it didn't seem to fix it either.

Here is my code, I am getting the error on line 9 and 10

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

html_text = requests.get('https://www.diyelectronics.co.za/store/353-printers')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text.text, 'lxml')

printers = soup.find('ul', class_='product_list grid row')
for printer in printers:
    printer_price = printer.find('span', class_='price product-price')
    printer_name = printer.find('h5', class_='product-name-container')

    print(f'''
    Printer Name: {printer_name}
    Printer Price: {printer_price}
    ''')
```

Comment: `printers = soup.find('ul', class_='product_list grid row')` --> `printers = soup.find_all('ul', class_='product_list grid row')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are multiple `<ul>` elements with class of `product_list grid row`, you should use `.find_all()` instead of `.find()`:

```py
printers = soup.find_all('ul', class_='product_list grid row')
```

Comment: That fixed it but I don't quite understand why. I understand why you would use find_all() since there is more than 1 <ul> element. But why does that change the code being seen from Pythons .find() to BeutifulSoups .find()
I am still new but I just want to learn and avoid making mistakes?

Comment: because if you use, `.find()` it will return the first occurrence which is a string like, and then you're looping through this string and calling `.find()` for each character in that string and it will cause the error. @JonathanLangford

Comment: Oh I see now, thank you very much! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

To get the required data, you need to get a "container", which is a CSS selector called [class selector](https://serpapi.com/blog/web-scraping-with-css-selectors-using-python/#class_selector) that contains all the information about the printers we need as child elements.

In our case, this is the ".right-block" selector. Have a look at the [SelectorGadget](https://selectorgadget.com/) Chrome extension to easily pick selectors by clicking on the desired element in your browser (*not always works perfectly*).

[Check code in online IDE](https://replit.com/@denisskopa/scrape-website-using-beatifulsoup#main.py).

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, json, lxml

html = requests.get("https://www.diyelectronics.co.za/store/353-printers", timeout=30)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "lxml")

printers_data = []

for result in soup.select(".right-block"):
  printer_name = result.select_one(".product-name").text.strip()
  printer_price = result.select_one(".product-price").text.strip()

  printers_data.append({
    "printer_name" : printer_name,
    "printer_price" : printer_price
  })

print(json.dumps(printers_data, indent=3))
```

Example output

```json
[
   {
      "printer_name": "DIYElectronics Prusa i3 Premium Kit",
      "printer_price": "R 6,999.99"
   },
   {
      "printer_name": "DIYElectronics Prusa i3 Premium Kit Assembled",
      "printer_price": "R 9,499.95"
   }
]
```